# SQL query 'where clause' for matching strings

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Use-Case: I want to select all entries from table t123, where field 'text' of the table is NOT a subset string of 'text_target'.

For example:

```
text_target = 'abf'
```

t123 has entries like,

```
   name         text
1) record1      abc
2) record2      abd
3) record3      af
```

result should be records 1 and 2, since their 'text' field is not subset of text_target value 'abf'.

EDIT: corrected the question

Comment: Not clear: record 3 is also a subset of "abf" as it cotains "f"?

Comment: Your logic is unclear.  Please explain exactly why you only expect records 1 and 2.

Comment: Add some more sample data, and adjust the result, to make the question clearer.

Comment: So the text matches if it contains one or more characters from `abf` but exactly in that order?

Answer (score 1):

use  `like`

```
select * from t123 where text like'ab%'
```

Comment: What happened to `f`? Did you delete it to match the result?

Comment: @SalmanA here f will come but i thought i mis read thats why according sampe i edit

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to explode the string:

```
where ( (test like '%a%') +
        (test like '%b%') +
        (test like '%f%')
      ) <> length(test)
```

It is not obvious that even regular expressions can help.

However, looking at strings as sets with one element per letter sounds like a data modeling problem.  You may want to ask *another* question describing your data and suggestions on how you might design your database.

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/JLRJS14632) (thanks to Tim).

Comment: I guess my main problem is how to explode the string. Since my text_target string is not fixed as 'abf' only and it might be different for the next set of data. Can i generically explode the string to compare just with characters?

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but I suppose:

```
    select * 
    from t123 
    where not ( substring( text from 1 for 1 ) in ( 'a', 'b', 'f', ' ' )
            and substring( text from 2 for 1 ) in ( 'a', 'b', 'f', ' ' )
            and substring( text from 3 for 1 ) in ( 'a', 'b', 'f', ' ' ) )
```

could return those rows that contain other letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression. For instance, if we suppose that you want to retrieve records NOT containing characters from "text_target" ("abf") :

```
SELECT * FROM t123 WHERE NOT text RLIKE "a|b|f"
```

Comment: I guess i would want to use something more generic to fit my use case.  SELECT * FROM t123 WHERE NOT text RLIKE "<all characters of text_target>".        Is there something like this?